# How to Encrypt and Decrypt userid and password in java Struts2

Tags: java, http, https

I have Encrypted password and userid and that password saved in hash code format in database but I do not get Encrypted password and userid in Tamper Data Output Request.I want this for Security purpose.

```
 public boolean isLoginValid() throws Exception {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String userType = "";
    int i = 1;
    boolean mm = false;
    try {
        con = ConnectionDB.createConnection();

        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT user_id,login_password, IFNULL(mdlname, '') mdlname, IFNULL(surname, '') surname, " +
                "user_name,USER_TYPE,lock_status, CURDATE() as cdate FROM user_master WHERE user_id = ? " +
                "and deleted_status=0", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        pstmt.setString(1, this.getUserid());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

            if (!rs.getString("login_password").equals(getHashedPassword(this.getPassword()))) {

                throw new DuplicateException("UserID / Password You entered is incorrect.");
            }
            String loginTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
            UserBean ObjUserBean = new UserBean();
            ObjUserBean.setLoginName(this.getUserid().trim().toUpperCase());
            ObjUserBean.setUserName(rs.getString("user_name").replaceAll("$", " ").trim());

            ObjUserBean.setServerdate(rs.getString("cdate").trim());
            System.out.println("Server Date : " + ObjUserBean.getServerdate());
            ObjUserBean.setUserid(this.getUserid().trim());
            ObjUserBean.setTxtMdlName(rs.getString("mdlname").trim());
            ObjUserBean.setTxtSurName(rs.getString("surname").trim());

            if (rs.getString("USER_TYPE").equals("S")) {
                throw new DuplicateUserTypeException("UserID / Password You entered is incorrect.");
            } else if (rs.getString("USER_TYPE").equals("A")) {
                throw new DuplicateUserTypeException("UserID / Password You entered is incorrect.");
            } else if (rs.getString("USER_TYPE").equals("N")) {
                ObjUserBean.setRoleName("Online User");
            } else {
                ObjUserBean.setRoleName("Offline User");
            }
            ObjUserBean.setLoginDate(loginTime);
            ObjUserBean.setUserInfo();
```

HashCode method

```
 public String getHashedPassword(String pstrPassword) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest objMsgDigest;
    try {
        objMsgDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        objMsgDigest.update(pstrPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    byte byteHash[] = objMsgDigest.digest();
    String strHashPwd = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < byteHash.length; i++) {

        // for (byte aByteHash : byteHash) {
        strHashPwd += Integer.toHexString(byteHash[i] & 0xff);
    }
    return strHashPwd;
}
```

Comment: Why you can not get the encreypted password or userId, if you know the userId and password, encrypt it again and query the value. What is the exact problem. Maybe it is better to add some code.

Comment: I am getting same password and userid which I have entered at the time of login  in tamper data ongoing request and password is getting hash code format in database so I want encrypted password and userid in tamper data ongoing request

Comment: What exactly is `Tamper Data Output Request`?

Comment: tamper data in Mozilla firefox

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. So you are examining data which is sent from client to server and wish that it should be encrypted?

Comment: yes sir right....it should be encrypted

Comment: Just don't. Read about https.

Comment: You're doing this wrong. Your SELECT statement should be doing the matching of both the user ID and the password. If you get a row that matches, the user is logged in. If not, no such user or wrong oassword, and you don't want to know the difference at any level of your application.